# Grails Update a List in GSP (View) and then submit with a button

Tags: list, grails, controller, gsp

Imagine you have a table displaying a list of books (like the index does) and you want to make changes in a column called "Sold" (a checkbox for example). So once you finish "Checking" the books you have sold, you click a Button to save! How do you send back that list to the controller and update it?

So, the code is something like this, in the controller:

def aMethod(){
...
[bookInstanceList: myBookList]
}

In the GSP:

```
    <g:each in="${bookInstanceList}" status="i" var="bookInstance">
        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

            <td><g:link action="show" id="${bookInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: bookInstance, field: "author")}</g:link></td>
            <td><g:checkBox name="sold" value="${bookInstance?.sold}" /></td>
            <td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
```

The idea is with the checkbox let the user change the "Sold" value from that book, and then make a submit with a Button. How can I save my new bookInstanceList?

Thank you very much

Comment: This cannot be done with pure grails. In my opinion, the best route is to introduce Javascript that will determine which books have been "sold", and submit that list to the controller.

Comment: There is nothing called out in the OP which cannot be done with pure Grails or that requires Javascript.  There may be reasons not specified in the post that he might want to use Javascript but as written, he can do this without Javascript.

Comment: You are correct, I spoke too soon. Your sample app is a great way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple sample app at https://github.com/jeffbrown/books which shows one way you could do this.  Run the app, open the default index page, click on the link and that will take you to a page where you can click checkboxes and update the library of books.

Files of interest are https://github.com/jeffbrown/books/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/com/demo/BookController.groovy and https://github.com/jeffbrown/books/blob/master/grails-app/views/book/index.gsp.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Woow, thank you very much! you did a mini project for demonstration thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've removed some of the markup for brevity and to bring focus to the important bits.  This is one way of doing it without relying on Javascript and what do you know, it is pure grails.  Never say never, @rmlan.

```
<g:form action="updateSold" controller="book">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <g:each in="${bookInstanceList}" status="i" var="bookInstance">
            <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
               <td><g:link action="show" id="${bookInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: bookInstance, field: "title")}</g:link></td>
               <td>
                   <g:checkBox name="sold" value="${bookInstance.sold}" />
                   <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${bookInstance.id}" />
               </td>
           </tr>
        </g:each>
     </tbody>
   </table>
   <g:submitButton name="updateSold" value="Update" />
</g:form>
```

This is the controller action:

```
def updateSold() {
   def solds = params.list('sold')
   def ids = params.list('id')

   ids.eachWithIndex { id, idx ->
      if (solds[idx]) {
          // the book's sold has been checked, so update it to TRUE           
      } else {
         // the books sold has not been checked, so update it to FALSE
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You'll find that this solution works for 99.9% of browsers out there. However, I'm going to be *that guy* and point out that the W3 spec for forms, in fact, does not guarantee order for form params. Therefore, trusting that the two arrays are indexed the same is not foolproof. Just sayin...

Comment: The issue here isn't just the W3 spec details but also the params.list(...) method makes no claim about the order of the elements in the list that is returned.  You probably really should not be relying on that order.  The sample that I linked in a different answer here deals with the ordering issue by using indexed param names like book[index goes here].